# Alert custom attribute value jquery table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the attribute value but it says its undefined.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".try").click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("value"));
    });
});
```

```html
<table id="try" class="try" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<td style="background:#80FF80;" value="WD">WD</td>
<td style="background:#FFFF80;" value="RD">RD</td>
<td style="background:#879FDE;" valu ="OD">OD</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include child element to your selector. Also your html isn't correct. You are missing open `tr`:

```js
$(".try tr td").click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr("value"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="try" class="try" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="background:#80FF80;" value="WD">WD</td>
    <td style="background:#FFFF80;" value="RD">RD</td>
    <td style="background:#879FDE;" value="OD">OD</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```